# Process outgoing mail from mail server with PHP

Tags: php, email

Is there any simple solution to get how many mail that have been sent, from the mail server by PHP?

I want to keep track of how many emails that have been sent to specific customers.

Comment: What mailserver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple add another column in the customer table `nos_mails`. Everytime you send a mail to your customer just update the value. I am assuming you know how to update a specific column of a specific row

Comment: I'm not using PHP to send mail. We use original mail clients here, that. The mail is processed by our own mail server. Now I want to grab this kind of statistics from our mail server with PHP. Is this possible?